# Как работает разрыв строки при возврате return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, f-strings

Как вывести f-строку в выводе return в несколько строк?

Имеем такой код:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, attr3):
        self._attr1 = attr1
        self._attr2 = attr2
        self._attr3 = attr3

    @property
    def attr1(self):
        return self._attr1

    @attr1.setter
    def attr1(self, value):
        self._attr1 = value

    @property
    def attr2(self):
        return self._attr2

    def set_attr2(self, value):
        self._attr2 = value

    attr2 = property(fset=set_attr2)

    def show_info(self):
        return f'attr1: {self.attr1}' + f"\n" + f'attr2: {self.attr2}'
```

Вводим в консоли:

```
class1.show_info()
```

Получаем:

```
'attr1: Attr1\nattr2: Attr2'
```

При использовании:

```
return f'attr1: {self.attr1}\nattr2: {self.attr2}'
```

результат тот же.

Вывод в идеале должен быть таким:

```
attr1: Attr1
attr2: Attr2
```

Comment: Код у вас немного кривоват в плане табуляций и `attr2 = ...` видимо должен быть `self.attr2 = ...`, но вообще `print(s.show_info())` работает именно так, как вам нужно. А если просто смотреть строку, то ну там и будет внутри `\n`, а как вы хотели?

Comment: Я написал в вопросе каким должен быть вывод. Кроме как через ```print()``` нельзя в несколько строк вывести?

Comment: Это и есть построчно. Просто напечатайте ее при помощи print

Comment: @МихаилДемин А куда вы выводите то? На печать через `print` и при выводе в файл будет как вы хотите - в две строки. Где у вас не в две строки получается, куда и как вы выводите?

Comment: Вывожу в консоль. Это не принципиально куда. Хочу понять можно ли выводить строки с разрывом простым ```return```

Comment: Если вы выводите в интерактивную консоль `IPython`, то он там может `repr` вызывать от вывода и показывать исходное содержимое строки. Хотите печатать - печатайте через `print`. А если вы в том же `Jupyter Notebook` введёте имя переменной, то фактически вызовется `print(repr(переменная))` и вы увидите именно что экранированные спецсимволы, а не то, как они на печать выводятся.

Comment: Я в PyCharm с этим столкнулся и заинтересовался.

Comment: В показанном вами коде нет никакого вывода, return не имеет никакого отношения к выводу. А если запихнуть эту строку в print, то выведется две строки как положено

Comment: @МихаилДемин Ну я вам полностью объяснил, что происходит. Консоль `PyCharm` - это тоже `IPython`, если я ничего не путаю.

Comment: @andreymal насчет ```print()``` все понятно. Вопрос был почему ```return``` не выводит так же как ```print()``` и можно ли обойтись без него.

Comment: @МихаилДемин `return` НИЧЕГО НИКУДА НЕ ВЫВОДИТ! `return` ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ. ВЫВОД К `return` НИКАК НЕ ОТНОСИТСЯ.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за разъяснения. Подскажите пожалуйста как комментарий пометить в качестве ответа на вопрос здесь?

Comment: @МихаилДемин Ну я могу вынести свой комментарий в виде ответа, который про `IPython` или который вынести? Комментарий нельзя отметить как ответ. За капслок выше извините, я думал вы так и не поняли. )

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за разъяснения. Не ожидал, что мой вопрос будет всем интересен. Всем добра!

Comment: @CrazyElf да комментарий про IPython отправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: @CrazyElf стандартная интерактивная консоль python работает так же

Comment: @andreymal Стандартная интерактивная консоль и `IPython` - это таки разные вещи? Я немного не в теме )

Answer (score 2):

`return` просто возвращает значение строки "как есть", он ничего никуда не выводит. Если же вы сами выводите результат работы вашей функции в интерактивную консоль `IPython` (в ячейке `Jupyter Notebook` или в консоли `PyCharm`), то фактически при этом у показываемых объектов вызывается метод `repr`, чтобы более наглядно показать вам их содержимое. То есть как будто вызывается следующий код (можете сами запустить такой код с вашей строкой и убедиться):

```
print(repr(строка)) # строка или любой другой объект
```

В результате у строки показываются все спецсимволы в "сыром" виде. Хотите печатать строку так, чтобы управляющие символы делали то, что они должны делать при выводе на консоль (например, переводить строку) - просто печатайте строку через `print` и всё будет как нужно.